# Creating World Map on Webots

Tags: robotics, webots

I need to create a simulation of a track-based event on Webots, which has multiple challenges in it ( Line Sensors, Obstacle avoidance, slopes.) How should I go ahead with creating the world map? How do I add the lines(black or white) for the line sensor application of the robot?

Answer (score 0):

If your floor is supposed to be flat, I would simply suggest adding a 'Floor' object in Webots and then you can define the appearance (i.e. include the black and white lines) of the floor.

If now already done, I strongly recommend following the Webots tutorial, in particular this one explain how to create a simulation environment:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-2-modification-of-the-environment